# Converting ''NodeList' item to int() in Python?

Tags: python, xml, variables, type-conversion, urllib2

I'm trying to convert a 'NodeList' object to an int() with the following code.

```
# DEFINE DATA FROM URL
dom = minidom.parse(urllib2.urlopen(url))

# SELECT AMOUNT
amount = dom.getElementsByTagName('amount')

# DEFINE VARIABLE AS INT
amount = int(amount)
```

When I run it, I get:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NodeList'

Thanks in advance for the help.

EDIT: Two example Nodes are:

```
<DOM Element: amount at 0x10e5c87a0>
<amount currency ="USD">142113</amount>

<DOM Element: amount at 0x10eccfcf8>
<amount currency="USD">140787</amount>
```

Comment: Can I ask you what did you try, so far?

Comment: iterate over the "amount" var, as that is clearly an iterator/list, and print them out to see what type they are.

Comment: `[int(a) for a in amount]`

Comment: @geckos I just placed that where I have my # DEFINE VARIABLE AS INT line and it did not work.

Comment: Did you got a ValueError?

Comment: Try `amount = [int(a.data) for a in amount]`

Comment: @geckos It doesn't return a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use requests and BeautifulSoup:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
amounts = soup.select('amount') # A list of amount tags    
for amount in amounts:
    print(int(amount.text))
```